# Oracle database, moving changes between databases

Tags: oracle, plsql

We have application where all logic is implemented in oracle database using pl/sql.

We have different oracle databases for development and production.

When developer make changes in development database after testing we move changes from development database to production database using schema compare tool of toad. Problem here is that developer must have password of production database. We want only admin to know this password.

Can somebody advice me better way of moving changes between databases without need of having production database password, what is best practice for this ?

I posted this question on oracle OTN forums and got some advices there. Maybe it will be interesting for somebody.
Her is a [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3557049)

Comment: Doing a diff is a really bad way of deploying changes. All PL/SQL code should be stored in a version control system (Subversion, Git, ...) and applied to the target database by using those scripts. Then the admin only needs to apply the (most recent) scripts from the version control system.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend to use comparison tools for generating of database migration scripts.
Development and production databases (and also test databases) must be identical except for current changes made by developers in development databases. Generally speaking this assertion is not correct, because there are many kinds of differencies between development and production databases, e.g. partitioned objects, additional objects for audit (triggers, tables), replication-based objects (snapshots), different tablespaces etc.
Every developer must know, what changes were made by him and applied to development database.
If developer was able to change schema and data in developer database, then he/she must be able to create programs for these DDL and DML changes.

To delegate the same developer an ability to run these migration programs on production database is a bad idea. But if you don't have a better way of database migration, then you can use one of following:

```
1. Configure Oracle authentication by OS. OS authentication allows Oracle to pass
   control of user authentication to the operating system.

2. TOAD can save passwords without disclose them. DBA will insert required password
   to local TOAD installation at developer PC (if developers use PC).
```